# How to parse twitter search result using rest API

Tags: java, json, api, twitter

I tried to parse the result of using rest API. It seemed that the get search/tweet API returned Json object instead of Json array. My question is: how can I separate each result returned if the whole thing returned is an object instead of an array?

Here is my code:

public class Search {

```
private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // If you choose to use a callback, "oauth_verifier" will be the return
    // value by Twitter (request param)
    String s="#NHL";
    System.out.println(getTweets(s));
}

public static String getTweetsString(String param) {
    OAuthService service = new ServiceBuilder()
            .provider(TwitterApi.SSL.class).apiKey(AuthInfo.API_KEY)
            .apiSecret(AuthInfo.API_SECRET).build();

    Token accessToken = new Token(AuthInfo.ACCESS_TOKEN,
            AuthInfo.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

    OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET,
            PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL);
    request.addQuerystringParameter("q",param);
    request.addQuerystringParameter("count", "2");

    service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
    Response response = request.send();

    System.out.println();
    return response.getBody();
}

public static ArrayList<Tweet> getTweets(String param){
    ArrayList<Tweet> result = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
    String tweets = getTweetsString(param);

    try {
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(tweets.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(is);
        JsonArray lists = reader.readArray();
        for(JsonObject rs: lists.getValuesAs(JsonObject.class)){
            System.out.println(rs);
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        return result;
}
```

}

The following error showed:
 Cannot read JSON array, found JSON object

Thanks for you help!!!!

Comment: Also, I cannot use twitter4j. Professors doesn't allow us to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Link should get you going in your JSON parsing in Java(http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/)

But since you are trying to parse the Array of JSON objects that Twitter api's return, have a look at this example...
http://www.bridgefarmconsulting.com/blog/twitter-authentication/
In the end of the blog post you'll see that the writer has written a class which is being used for parsing the JSON object...
So get your response string, create your parser class based on the keys which you would like to access and the parse it...

Hope you got the idea...

Comment: Coll Thanks for your help! I just found that in fact, the JSON object returned had a field called "status" which was actually JSON object of tweets