# twitter streaming API java search by date

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api

I made a twitter application and got `application settings` and `access token`.

I can use the official java library `hbc-core` and `hbc-twitter4j` or twitter4j.org's `twitter4j`.

- not sure how to authenticate and start the stream(which functions/instances to use)
- what function/instance to query

for example, I want to search for all(the ones in the streaming API) posts with hashtag **#hashtagname** on 2016-02-13 (date is within one week of request). I want to return `tweet id`, `user id`, `number of retweets`, and `number of replies`

Comment: are you debugging code or are you not sure how to begin using twitters api with java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using twitters/hbc [quickstart](https://github.com/twitter/hbc). You need to have [maven](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) installed. Then you can just `git install` the quickstart and run the sample app with:

```
mvn install && mvn exec:java -pl hbc-example -Dconsumer.key=XYZ -Dconsumer.secret=SECRET -Daccess.token=ABC -Daccess.token.secret=ABCSECRET
```

and putting your credentials after the `=` in quotes. If you look at the source code to this you can use this code as a playground to get a the hang of how to use this client with Twitters API. Then just look into the code [examples](https://github.com/twitter/hbc/tree/master/hbc-example/src/main/java/com/twitter/hbc/example) and pick what you need to achieve the functionality you're looking for and combine that with the endpoints you would need from twitter, specifically [these](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track) to search for hashtags and obtain json like so

```
{
  "created_at": "Mon Feb 13 08:47:02 +0000 2017",
  "id": 831062112478822400,
  "id_str": "831062112478822400",
  "text": "You've been doing #DataReporting all wrong. This is how you create powerful insights with #data:\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/w5rHjKMGza",
  "display_text_range": [0, 140],
  "source": "\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/bufferapp.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eBuffer\u003c\/a\u003e",
  "truncated": true,
  "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str": null,
  "in_reply_to_user_id": null,
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null,
  "in_reply_to_screen_name": null,
  "user": {
    "id": 2953426294,
    "id_str": "2953426294",
    "name": "Developing Edge",
    "screen_name": "ptdevedge",
    "location": "United Kingdom",
    "url": "http:\/\/developingedge.com\/",
    "description": null,
    "protected": false,
    "verified": false,
    "followers_count": 455,
    "friends_count": 225,
    "listed_count": 132,
    "favourites_count": 44,
    "statuses_count": 854,
    "created_at": "Wed Dec 31 16:42:36 +0000 2014",
    "utc_offset": 0,
    "time_zone": "London",
    "geo_enabled": false,
    "lang": "en-gb",
    "contributors_enabled": false,
    "is_translator": false,
    "profile_background_color": "000000",
    "profile_background_image_url": "http:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png",
    "profile_background_image_url_https": "https:\/\/abs.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme1\/bg.png",
    "profile_background_tile": false,
    "profile_link_color": "C56200",
    "profile_sidebar_border_color": "000000",
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color": "000000",
    "profile_text_color": "000000",
    "profile_use_background_image": false,
    "profile_image_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/713668391710638080\/R1-V_Zvh_normal.jpg",
    "profile_image_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/713668391710638080\/R1-V_Zvh_normal.jpg",
    "profile_banner_url": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/2953426294\/1450889452",
    "default_profile": false,
    "default_profile_image": false,
    "following": null,
    "follow_request_sent": null,
    "notifications": null
  },
  "geo": null,
  "coordinates": null,
  "place": null,
  "contributors": null,
  "is_quote_status": false,
  "extended_tweet": {
    "full_text": "You've been doing #DataReporting all wrong. This is how you create powerful insights with #data: https:\/\/t.co\/zSXxWLy0fY https:\/\/t.co\/BcbvZdewKb",
    "display_text_range": [0, 120],
    "entities": {
      "hashtags": [{
        "text": "DataReporting",
        "indices": [18, 32]
      }, {
        "text": "data",
        "indices": [90, 95]
      }],
      "urls": [{
        "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/zSXxWLy0fY",
        "expanded_url": "http:\/\/bit.ly\/powerful-data-insights",
        "display_url": "bit.ly\/powerful-data-\u2026",
        "indices": [97, 120]
      }],
      "user_mentions": [],
      "symbols": [],
      "media": [{
        "id": 831062108943024131,
        "id_str": "831062108943024131",
        "indices": [121, 144],
        "media_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C4iGlb3WAAMAwAL.jpg",
        "media_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C4iGlb3WAAMAwAL.jpg",
        "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/BcbvZdewKb",
        "display_url": "pic.twitter.com\/BcbvZdewKb",
        "expanded_url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/ptdevedge\/status\/831062112478822400\/photo\/1",
        "type": "photo",
        "sizes": {
          "medium": {
            "w": 1024,
            "h": 768,
            "resize": "fit"
          },
          "thumb": {
            "w": 150,
            "h": 150,
            "resize": "crop"
          },
          "large": {
            "w": 1024,
            "h": 768,
            "resize": "fit"
          },
          "small": {
            "w": 680,
            "h": 510,
            "resize": "fit"
          }
        }
      }]
    },
    "extended_entities": {
      "media": [{
        "id": 831062108943024131,
        "id_str": "831062108943024131",
        "indices": [121, 144],
        "media_url": "http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C4iGlb3WAAMAwAL.jpg",
        "media_url_https": "https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/C4iGlb3WAAMAwAL.jpg",
        "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/BcbvZdewKb",
        "display_url": "pic.twitter.com\/BcbvZdewKb",
        "expanded_url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/ptdevedge\/status\/831062112478822400\/photo\/1",
        "type": "photo",
        "sizes": {
          "medium": {
            "w": 1024,
            "h": 768,
            "resize": "fit"
          },
          "thumb": {
            "w": 150,
            "h": 150,
            "resize": "crop"
          },
          "large": {
            "w": 1024,
            "h": 768,
            "resize": "fit"
          },
          "small": {
            "w": 680,
            "h": 510,
            "resize": "fit"
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  },
  "retweet_count": 0,
  "favorite_count": 0,
  "entities": {
    "hashtags": [{
      "text": "DataReporting",
      "indices": [18, 32]
    }, {
      "text": "data",
      "indices": [90, 95]
    }],
    "urls": [{
      "url": "https:\/\/t.co\/w5rHjKMGza",
      "expanded_url": "https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/831062112478822400",
      "display_url": "twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/8\u2026",
      "indices": [98, 121]
    }],
    "user_mentions": [],
    "symbols": []
  },
  "favorited": false,
  "retweeted": false,
  "possibly_sensitive": false,
  "filter_level": "low",
  "lang": "en",
  "timestamp_ms": "1486975622659"
}
```

Comment: Thank you,  I didn't look into the examples in the api source files. It's usually that not well written. If I can ask, is there a function in the api that parses the Json into a Java object or list, or do I need to use an external library/function for that?

Comment: you're gunna need an external library for that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694477/how-to-parse-twitter-search-result-using-rest-api

Comment: @JonathanPortorreal I tried the example "FilterStreamExample.java" from mentioned link but how to fetch the dates according to specific date with hbc in java